# Pose of camera from the pose of marker

Tags: c++, opencv

I am currently working on a task to localize a vehicle using computer vision. I am using `OpenCV` with `C++`. I implemented ArUco marker to get the pose of the camera placed on the vehicle.

I used of the following function to estimate pose of the marker :

```
cv::aruco::estimatePoseSingleMarkers(markerCorners, markerLength, camMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs,tvecs)
```

Later I found out that `rvecs` and `tvecs` are 1x1 arrays with 3 channels `(openCVDataType=CV_8UC3)`.

Now, I get R(3x3) matrix from `cv::Rodrigues` function say it's Ri.

In order to get the pose of the camera `w.r.t` to marker, after a considerable amount of research I found out that the inverse transforms have to be taken.
I got inverse if Ri.

Now to get inverse of translation vector it is just the multiplication of the above inverse with the translation vector (tvecs).

I am fairly new to c++ and my issues are:

1. Is my approach correct in finding the pose of camera `w.r.t` marker?
2. I am unable to change the `tvecs` into a `mat` object so that there is no multiplication error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method **estimatePoseSingleMarkers** uses [cv::solvePnP](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#bool%20solvePnP(InputArray%20objectPoints,%20InputArray%20imagePoints,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs,%20OutputArray%20rvec,%20OutputArray%20tvec,%20bool%20useExtrinsicGuess,%20int%20flags)) method within.
That's why for camera pose estimation you need to perform next:

```
Mat R;
cv::Rodrigues(rvec, R); // calculate your object pose R matrix

camR = R.t();  // calculate your camera R matrix

Mat camRvec;
Rodrigues(R, camRvec); // calculate your camera rvec

Mat camTvec= -camR * tvec; // calculate your camera translation vector
```

It seems that it fits your guesses

Comment: in the last line I thought it's -R.t() * tvec.
Am I right?

Comment: @slayer2309 and tenta4 I think it's the other way around **estimateposeSingleMarkers** gives the camera pose w.r.t marker coordinate system and one needs to do the above steps as said by tenta4 to get the marker pose w.r.t to camera coordinate system or am i wrong? refer this
http://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/22/extrinsic/

Comment: @Komms See the documentation (https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html#ga84dd2e88f3e8c3255eb78e0f79571bd1): The returned transformation is the one that transforms points from each marker coordinate system to the camera coordinate system. So you need to invert it

Comment: It's a shame that they don't have any to input actual object points from a known world coordinate system. It always takes center of marker as 0

Answer (score 0):

Method of Rodriguez provides you a rotation matrix. Make a 4*4 transformation matrix with the help of rotation matrix and translation matrix. Inversing the transformation matrix will provide the pose of the camera with respect to marker. For the equations, just google, it's quite simple and available. You need to extract rotation and translation from the inverse transformation matrix.